# No se de donde proviene la url en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola chic@s estoy empezando con jquery y tengo una duda que seguro que esmuy sencilla pero no acabo de encontrar la información en internet. Os pongo en contexto. Tengo en un proyecto una peticion ajax y dentro de esta petición se encuentra este linea de código.

`jquery('<form action="/esto es/una/url" method="get" </form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove()`

El caso es que donde va la url la busco en el proyecto y no la encuentro no se de donde está sacando esa url. ¿Me podeis ayudar? me ha parecido raro no encontrar nada en internet. o yo no lo he entendido bien. Un salkudo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No tengo muy claro a lo que te refieres, pero si te fijas en el código paso a paso, veras que primero agrega el texto en el body (`append`), luego envia el formulario que acaba de agregar (`submit`) y por último lo borra todo (`remove`).  Es decir, ya no lo vas a encontrar en el fuente de la página, pero teoricamente se abrá ejecutado sin que lo veas (y quizas te ha redirigido a esa url tambien si ha salido bien ese codigo, cosa que dudo porque el primer form no esta cerrado).

Comment: parece un ejemplo sacado de una web. Normalmente donde ponen "/esto es/una/url" debes cambiarlo por la url que quieres probar. Por otro lado, el contenido que se copia en body con el appendTo esta mal cerrado (falta un > despues del "get")

Comment: @masterguru si, la etiqueta no está cerrada por un error mio al formular la pregunta, pero si tiene el cierre. Esa url la he puesto para no poner la original que pone /guardar/csv . funciona bien todo. Pero tengo que hacer algo parecido y usar este ejemplo pero me tengo que inventar un url para ponerla y no se de donde se saca o donde debo crear la url nueva.  Queri usar este ejemplo en el codigo que tengo para fijarme como hacer uno nuevo, pero no se como se implmentan las url, porque en el codigo la url /guardar/csv no me aparece por ningun lado. Para emular el que ya tengo y funciona.

Comment: @Jakala como he puesto en el comentario anterior la url/guardar/csv funciona, pero yo quiero crear una nueva y no se a donde ir en el codigo para encontrar esa url. Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: Dificilmente podremos ayudarte si no pones más código relacionado. Es decir, si tu no eres capaz de encontrar ni la primera url, teniendo el código delante, imagínate nosotros sin tener nada de nada ni saber de que proyecto estas hablando.

Comment: la url que tienes es solo "/url/guardar/csv"? no tiene algo tipo http://hostname.tld ? si no lo tiene, entonces se presupone que es del dominio donde esta alojando la aplicacion. tampoco nos cuentas cual es el servidor que tienes (es un php, node, algun otro...) como esta configurado (que dominios tiene de servicio) ? el /guardar/csv podria ser una ruta definida en un router de tu aplicacion, o de una aplicacion de backend, o podria ser hasta un "/guardar/csv.php"... podrias llegar a tener un archivo `csv` que contenga el codigo a tratar...